# Check if document exists or not in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I  want to check if a document with specific field value does exist or not in elasticsearch.

I have gone through internet but only found how to check if a field exists or not.

My Index/Type is

```
/twitter/user
```

username is one field in document.

I want to check if `username="xyz"` exists or not in this Type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can query with size `0`. `total` value will give you an idea that doc exists or not.

```
GET /twitter/user/_search
{"size": 0,
  "query": {"match": {
  "username": "xyz"
}}}
```

Edited --

`_count api can be used as well.`

```
GET /twitter/user/_count
{ "query": {"match": {
  "username": "xyz"
}}}
```

Comment: This will be helpful, return only total number of records

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-exists.html):

> If all you want to do is to check whether a document exists—you’re not interested in the content at all—then use the `HEAD` method instead of the `GET` method. `HEAD` requests don’t return a body, just HTTP headers:

```
curl -i -XHEAD http://localhost:9200/twitter/user/userid
```

> Elasticsearch will return a `200 OK` status code if the document exists ... and a `404 Not Found` if it doesn’t exist

*Note:* `userid` is the value of the `_id` field.

Comment: is it possible to translate that thanks to the node.js client?

Comment: yes: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_exists

Answer (score 2):

simply search the document, if it exists it will return result otherwise not

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/twitter/user/_search?q=username:xyz
```

and the exact what are you looking for is

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/twitter/user/_search/exists?q=username:xyz
```

it will return exists `true` or `false`

```
{
    "exists": false
}
```

Comment: First query return the record , but i dont want the record, and other is not exist in elasticsearch 5.* . Thanks

Comment: yeah i tried this query in older version, so not sure for latest version

Answer (score 2):

You can use term query with size 0. See below query for reference:

```
POST twitter/user/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "username": "xyz"
        }
    },
    "size" : 0
}
```

Response:

```
{
"took": 1,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 0,
  "hits": []
}
}
```

You will get total document count in **hits.total** and then you can check for *count > 0*